# C++ auto cannot deduce type with default template parameter

Tags: c++

I notice that if I write:

```
template<typename T = int> void Test(T t) {};
```

then the following code does not compile:

```
auto x = Test;
```

However, this code does, and deduces *x* to be *void (*x)(int t)*:

```
auto x = Test<int>;
```

I'm just wondering why it does not just assume the type parameter is int in the first case and treat it the same as the second one?

Comment: I don't suppose you tried `auto x = Test<>` ?

Comment: If there is a function template in the overload set, deduction is not performed in general: https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct.call#6.1 Why it was decided that way, I don't know.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a function with a default parameter, for example:

```
int f(int n=0);
```

Calling this function with this parameter defaulted is done by doing this:

```
int g=f();
```

and not this:

```
int g=f;
```

Same principle applies to template instantiations:

```
auto x = Test<>;
```

Comment: That's not really a good reason. `<>` can be omitted in most contexts on function templates.

Comment: I don't understand the reasoning here. Sure, `int g=f;` doesn't work, but `auto g=f;` which is the correct analogy to the OP's code, does. What does *calling* the function have to do with the OP's question at all?

Comment: `auto g=f` does not result in a function call, and just a `Test` does not result in an instantiated template either. `auto g=f` results in something else, other than a function call; and just a `Test` also results in something else, other than a template instantiation.

Comment: Thank you for responding. I guess what's surprising to me is that `auto g=f` just results in g not being an int and compiles, while `auto x=Test` results in a compilation error. I suppose Test<> does what I expect, but it seems weird that I can write `Test(1)` and it will assume that `T` is int, but it won't assume that if you write `auto x = Test`.